# Whats the best solution to recreate this array in c#?

Tags: c#

I tried many things but im not happy with the result, so i decided to ask: How can i recreate this array in c#?

```
local itemTable = {

["category1"] = {
    {"Test1",1463,0.4,0,13},
    {"Test2",1578,0.5,0,4},
    {"Test3",2683,1,0,6},
},

["category2"] = {
    {"Test4",328,0.4,90,5},
    {"Test5",1463,0.4,0,5},
    {"Test6",346,1,90,1.5},
},}
```

Btw. this array is from LUA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: _I tried many things_.  What things did you try?  Show those attempts.  Perhaps show the ones that get you the closest to your goal.

Comment: it can be a List of tuple

Comment: It depends also on what you are going to do with these data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't mention how you want to use the data, however I would do it this way:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>()
{
    { "category1", new Dictionary<string,List<double>>()
        {
            { "Test1", new List<double>{ 1463, 0.4, 0, 13 } },
            { "Test2", new List<double>{ 1578, 0.5, 0, 4 } },
            { "Test3", new List<double>{ 2683, 1, 0, 6 } },
        }
    },

    { "category2", new Dictionary<string,List<double>>()
        {
            { "Test4", new List<double>{ 328, 0.4, 90, 5 } },
            { "Test5", new List<double>{ 1463, 0.4, 0, 5 } },
            { "Test6", new List<double>{ 346, 1, 90, 1.5 } },
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Doesn't this answer the OP's question?!

Comment: Someone probably down-voted you because direct answers on questions where it seems that OP doesn't have a clue what he is doing aren't encouraged here.